# Python pad list to be the size of the next multiplier of 6

Tags: python, list, vector, data-science, data-munging

I have a list and I want to ensure it's len is a multiplier of 6 and pad with zeros.
So if I have:
l1 = `[1,2,3,4]`
I will get

```
[1,2,3,4,0,0]

l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

will be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,0]
```

and `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
will be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of zeros multiplied by reminder after dividing the length of the list by 6 (it will create the required padding list), then finally add both the lists.

```py
>>> l2 + [0]*(len(l2)%6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0]
```